# Multivariable Calculus Triple Integrals Challenge Problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Show that the average of the reciprocal of the distance from a fixed point A outside a ball to points in the ball is equal to the reciprocal of the distance from A to the center of the ball. (This is related to the idea in physics that the gravitational attraction between a planet and a satellite is as if all the mass of the planet were at its center.)

I've tried setting things up on a coordinate axes to make things as symmetric as possible - but I am very confused on how to even begin to understand/solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Symmetry saves us

Let's say our ball and $A$ are represented by
$$
x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2,\quad (0,0,c)\quad(c>R)
$$
This of course does not compromise generality as we are free to choose our origin and coordinate axes.

[image]

As you can see the distance between $A$ and any point on a circle on the ball whose plane is parallel to $xy$-plane remains constant on the circle. So the average of reciprocal of distance along the circle in the figure is $\frac{1}{d}$. With this information at our disposal we only need to compute a single integral to get the average.

> Calculation of $d$

Suppose the smaller circle parallel to $xy$-plane in the figure is represented by
$$\begin{align}
&x^2+y^2=R^2-h^2,\quad z=h\\
\therefore&\; d^2=x^2+y^2+(z-c)^2=R^2+c^2-2ch
\end{align}$$

> We need to compute

$$\begin{align}
&\frac{\int_{-R}^R\frac{\,dh}{d}}{\int_{-R}^R\,dh}=\frac{1}{2R}\int_{-R}^R\frac{\,dh}{\sqrt{R^2+c^2-2ch}}=-\frac{1}{2cR}\sqrt{R^2+c^2-2ch}\Big{|}_{-R}^R=\frac{1}{c}
\end{align}$$
which is what we were supposed to get.

Comment: How did you do that picture?

Comment: @Anonymous I used a function called ParametricPlot3D available in Mathematica.

Comment: nice, thanks. (+1)